# Definition of Cartan subalgebra in Erdmann-Wildon

Tags: lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

Sorry in advance if this is too basic but I am just beginning to learn about lie algebras. I am reading *Introdution to Lie Algebras* by Karin Erdmann and Mark J. Wildon and I don't understand the definition of Cartan subalgebras (p. 94):

**Definition 10.2:** A Lie subalgebra $H$ of a Lie algebra $L$ is said to be a *Cartan subalgebra* (or CSA) if $H$ is abelian and every element $h\in H$ is semisimple, and moreover $H$ is maximal with these properties.

I understand what a "$h\in H$ is semisimple" means when $H$ is a semisimple Lie algebra ($n=0$ where $h=d+n$ is the Abstract Jordan decomposition, p. 87). However in our case $H$ isn't semisimple if $\dim H>0$, so I don't understand why this makes sense. I thought maybe it meant that $h$, seen as an element of $L$, is semisimple, but the authors emphasis after the definition that "we do not assume $L$ is semisimple in this definition".

What is the meaning of "$h\in H$ is semisimple"?

I'm thinking that this could mean $\mathsf{ad}(h)\in \mathsf{gl}(V)$ is diagonalisable (I'm just interested in the complex case), but I'm sure the authors would have stated explicitely that we can extend the definition to the non-semisimple case (or maybe I missed it).

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This definition of Cartan subalgebra seems only adapted to semisimple Lie algebras. The usual definition for a general (finite-dimensional) Lie algebra is a nilpotent subalgebra equal to its normalizer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semisimple elements are also defined for non-semisimple Lie algebras.

**Definition:** A semi-simple element of an abstract Lie algebra $L$ is an element $x\in L$ for which the adjoint linear transformation $\operatorname{ad}(x)$ is a semi-simple endomorphism of the vector space $L$".

Reference: See [here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Semi-simple_element).

Comment: Right, and maybe one should clarify that in the source, it means that every $h\in H$ is semisimple *as element of $L$*; i.e. the endomorphism $ad_L(h) \in End(L)$ is semisimple (not just it's restriction $ad_H(h)\in End(H)$, which by $H$ being abelian is identically $0$ anyway).

Answer (score 1):

You are right: it does mean $\mathrm{ad}(h)$ is diagonalisable.